# How to catch keypress and mouse up at the same time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can toogle the `ctrlBtn["pressed"]` to `true` when I press CTRL or ALT key on Mac. (inspecting by console.log)

However, when I trigger the `mouse up` it couldn't enter the `saveWord(selected)`.  `ctrlBtn["pressed"]` still stays `false`.

What a good practice to catch the keypress and mouse up at the same time.

I'm writing a chrome extension currently. The whole script is here! https://gist.github.com/weichenghsu/4bbb2d1b6c3d34d55a942c3c6713fa89

Thanks!

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    ... 
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var selected = selection.toString().trim();

        if (selected) {
            console.log(ctrlBtn);
            console.log(ctrlBtn["pressed"]);
            if (ctrlBtn["pressed"] == true) {
                saveWord(selected);
            }
            updateHighlighter();
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        ctrlBtn["pressed"] = false;
    });

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);


        if (e.keyCode == 17 || e.keyCode == 18) {
            ctrlBtn["pressed"] = true;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: `e.ctrlKey` and `e.altKey` can be used in `mouseup` event so the purpose of this complicated scheme isn't clear to me. Can you clarify?

Comment: @wOxxOm the whole script is here! https://gist.github.com/weichenghsu/4bbb2d1b6c3d34d55a942c3c6713fa89